# Want to open custom popup in react JavaScript using HTML5

Tags: html, reactjs

I tried this link:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zxLdgz

http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2012/10/creating-a-modal-window-with-html5-and-css3/

But its not working in:

I tried this code in jsx file

```
<a href="#openModal">Open Modal</a>

<div id="openModal" className="modalDialog">
    <div>
        <a href="#close" title="Close" className="close">X</a>
        <h2>Modal Box</h2>
        <p>This is a sample modal box that can be created using the powers of CSS3.</p>
        <p>You could do a lot of things here like have a pop-up ad that shows when your website loads, or create a login/register form for users.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also this code:

```
ondialog() 
{
    <dialog id="window">
        <h3>Sample Dialog!</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum, inventore!</p>
        <button id="exit">Close Dialog</button>
    </dialog>
}
```

on button click still no use

Answer (score 5):

There is actually no code here that open a modal, but you could do something like this using the ES6 class syntax and class properties (you might need to have the right babel configs for this)

```jsx
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class Page extends Component {

  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { modalActive: false }
  }

  openModal = () => {
    this.setState({ modalActive: true })
  }

  closeModal = () => {
    this.setState({ modalActive: false })
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.openModal}>Open modal</button>

        {this.state.modalActive && (
          <div className='modalDialog'>
            <a title='Close' onClick={this.closeModal}>X</a>
            <h2>Modal</h2>
            <p>This is a sample modal</p>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

What I'm basically doing is keeping a boolean in my state to define if the modal is shown or not and my condition on `this.state.modalActive` will render the modal if the value is trulthy.

Answer (score 0):

Adding an `open` attribute to your dialog will make it visible:

```
render () {
  return (
  <div>
    {this.state.modalActive && (
      <dialog className='modalDialog' open>
      </dialog>
    )}
  </div>
)
```

}